# Random Generate numbers and strings in unix of specific length

Tags: unix

I need to generate random numbers and strings in unix shell scripting .... like (193748c9-4567-8907-8543-4678953456bd) ... any help ??? thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to generate a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). You should have in your distro a command `uuidgen` which can do the work for you.

```sh
# Create UUID
uuidgen
b03108db-65f2-4d7c-b884-bb908d111400

# Create time based UUID
uuidgen -t
30799dba-881f-11e6-84ae-024206e5b105

# Create random UUID
uuidgen -r
a68eddcd-6eec-4b5e-846d-97b1161248e2
```

If you don't have that command, then you can use this python oneliner, as per this answer

```py
# Create UUID 
python -c 'import uuid; print str(uuid.uuid1())'

# Create random UUID
python -c 'import uuid; print str(uuid.uuid4())'
```